# How can i segment iTunes podcast on the basis of chapter

Tags: ios, itunes, podcasts, mp3

I have my own iTunes podcast series of approx 200mp3 which are directly feeded from my wordpress website. Link to iTunes: https://itunes.apple.com/in/podcast/bhagawad-geeta/id1148683227?mt=2

Now i want that these podcast be organized one after another and also segment it on the basis of chapters.

Can anyone help me on this that how to achieve this things for iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

To produce podcasts with chapters, I have found I need to use GarageBand(GB).

It supports creating podcasts with chapters. You will need to open each mp3 in GB and manually edit and set up the chapter divisions.

Or if you are seeking to combine each existing mp3 file as an existing chapter into longer podcasts with several chapters (existing mp3's) you will again need to do it manually in GB and republish as a podcast. There may be some other downloadable programs to make podcasts on the app or itunes store sites.

Quicktime can play published podcasts with chapters. I find the older Quicktime 7 better than the more recent Quicktime app.

I hope I have understood your question, and that this answers your question some what.

Comment: Thanks @Cam_Aust I will try using GarageBand and then will tell you whether it worked for me or not.

Comment: can't I make chapters directly without using any software. I have total of 207 mp3's.

Comment: I also wanted to ask that can i make my all the audio files in serial order. THey are now coming in random order which is not impressive for me...

Comment: I am not aware of an automatic process. Loading in several in sequential order, making each one a fresh chapter would not take a lot of time in GB. However, yes, with 207, it will take quite a while. Try searching for podcaste making software. You might find one that does what you want automatically.